# Sort by and filter by a different column in an IndexedDB object store

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Let's say I have an object store called `messages` and its structure is like

```
{
    "id": id, 
    "from": from, 
    "conversation": conversation, 
    "time": time,
    "text": text
}
```

Where apart from `text` everything is a number.

If I would like to read a conversation then I naturally get a cursor by running `store.index("conversation").openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(conversation))`, but I would also like the returned values be sorted by `time`, how can I implement this?

More to add, the object store has `id` as its primary key and the greater `id` is, the greater `time` is.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe try this:

```
function open() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const r = indexedDB.open('convos-by-time-test');
    r.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
      const conn = r.result;
      console.debug('Creating database', conn.name);
      const store = conn.createObjectStore(
      'conversations', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});
      store.createIndex('conversation-time', ['conversation', 'time']);
    };
    r.onsuccess = function(event) {
      resolve(r.result);
    };
  });
}

function addConversations(conn, convos) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const txn = conn.transaction('conversations', 'readwrite');
    txn.oncomplete = resolve;
    txn.onerror = _ => reject(txn.error);

    const store = txn.objectStore('conversations');
    for (const convo of convos) {
      store.put(convo);
    }
  });
}

function findConversationOrderByTime(conn, conversation) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const txn = conn.transaction('conversations');
    txn.onerror = _ => reject(txn.error);
    const store = txn.objectStore('conversations');
    const index = store.index('conversation-time');
    const lowerBound = [conversation, 0];
    const upperBound = [conversation, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER];
    const range = IDBKeyRange.bound(lowerBound, upperBound);
    const request = index.getAll(range);
    request.onsuccess = _ => resolve(request.result);
  });
}

function deleteDatabase(name) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(name);
    request.onsuccess = resolve;
    request.onerror = _ => reject(request.error);
  });
}

async function runTest() {
  console.debug('Starting test');
  const conn = await open();
  console.debug('Connected to database');

  const data = [];
  data.push({'from': '123', 'conversation': 'a', 'time': 1});
  data.push({'from': '456', 'conversation': 'd', 'time': 4});
  data.push({'from': '789', 'conversation': 'b', 'time': 2});
  data.push({'from': '012', 'conversation': 'b', 'time': 1});
  data.push({'from': '345', 'conversation': 'b', 'time': 3});
  data.push({'from': '678', 'conversation': 'c', 'time': 3});

  await addConversations(conn, data);
  console.debug('Added initial test data of %d objects', data.length);

  const targetConversation = 'b';
  const results = await findConversationOrderByTime(conn, targetConversation);
  console.debug(
  'Matched %d conversations with conversation value %s', results.length,
  targetConversation);

  for (const result of results) {
    console.debug('Result:', JSON.stringify(result));
  }

  conn.close();

  await deleteDatabase(conn.name);
  console.debug('Deleted database');

  console.debug('Test completed');
}
```

For why I think this works, see my other answers to questions about compound indices

Answer (score -2):

Lots of assumptions here with how you worded your question, would be easier if you posted some code you tried.

I am going to assume you query you database and get an array of objects returned

Something like this (making assumptions on how date is stored)

```
let conversation = [
  {"id": 1, "from":'from', "conversation":'conversation', "time": 1528735036499 },
  {"id": 3, "from":'from', "conversation":'conversation', "time":1528735087860},
  {"id": 4, "from":'from', "conversation":'conversation', "time":1528735111224},
  {"id": 2, "from":'from', "conversation":'conversation', "time": 1528735070207 }
]

let orderedConvo = conversation.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time)

console.log(orderedConvo)
```

You should use .sort() on your array and compare the times, currently its sorting oldest - newest if you want newest to oldest just switch to `b.time - a.time`

I specifically ordered the IDs 1-4 to show how they should be ordered by time. Here is a codeine with the sorted result

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEMqxB?editors=0011

Comment: That's not it, openCursor returns a cursor not an array, and a conversation may contain thousands of messages so using an array isn't very efficient